# bootsrap 3.1 pull main content first (on TOP) when mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have following grid structure

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="A" class="col-md-3">
        <div class="alert alert-info">A</div>
    </div>
      <div id="B" class="col-md-6">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">B</div>
    </div>
    <div id="C" class="col-md-3">
        <div class="alert alert-info">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to show `B` first when mobile (**But when big device other than mobile then it should show as above**) and also WHEN mobile all `A`,`B`,`C`will be in equal width. I have tried as following

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-6">
    <div class="alert alert-info">A</div>
</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-3">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">B</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="alert alert-info">C</div>
</div>
```

Also tried in many combination nothing working

WHEN big screen like desktop

[image: WHEN big scree like desktop]

When mobile

[image: When mobile]

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">B</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-6">
    <div class="alert alert-info">A</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="alert alert-info">C</div>
</div>
```

Or [DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/9wxzjgdb/2/).

Comment: same thing i applied in my main project now not working

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this without changing `div` order?? It is not possible for me to shift `B` from his place

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-4 " >B</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-6 col-sm-3" >A</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">C</div>
```

Comment: Tried, Not worked. Al `ABC` should be in full width when mobile and equal width

Comment: Need a clarification.
You want ABC in different rows on big screen and BAC in same row on mobile screen  . Right ?

Comment: <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4 col-md-push-0 col-md-12" >A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-pull-4 col-md-pull-0 col-md-12" >B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-12">C</div>

Comment: <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-4 " >B</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-6 col-sm-3" >A</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">C</div>

Answer (score 0):

I used javascript to implement this functionality. I am first finding bootstrap environment and according to it i am arranging divs.

```
var current='';
function findBootstrapEnvironment() {
    var envs = ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg'];

    var $el = $('<div>');
    $el.appendTo($('body'));

    for (var i = envs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var env = envs[i];

        $el.addClass('hidden-'+env);
        if ($el.is(':hidden')) {
            $el.remove();
            return env;
        }
    }
}
if(findBootstrapEnvironment()=="sm"&&findBootstrapEnvironment()!=current){
  current=findBootstrapEnvironment();
  var a=$('.row').children()[0];
  var b=$('.row').children()[2];
  $('.row').children()[0].remove();
  $('.row').children()[1].remove();
  $('.row').append(a);
  $('.row').append(b);
  console.log(current);
}

$( window ).resize(function() {
if((findBootstrapEnvironment()=="sm"||findBootstrapEnvironment()=="md")&&findBootstrapEnvironment()!=current){
  current=findBootstrapEnvironment();
  var a=$('.row').children()[0];
  var b=$('.row').children()[2];
  $('.row').children()[0].remove();
  $('.row').children()[1].remove();
  $('.row').append(a);
  $('.row').append(b);
  console.log(current);
}
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/oog0gdph/